# Capture output from subprocess.Popen commands that execute further processes

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

SOLVED: User error.

I have a python program that must utilize some other proprietary scripts that I can't access/control. I launch the proprietary (bash) script using

```
logfile = open('/file', 'a')
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/script/script','argument'], stdout=logfile, stderr=logfile)
proc.wait()
```

Unfortunately, the bash script that I have to execute then executes a Java script and the output of that Java script is getting printed to my terminal instead of the `logfile` that I've specified in the `subprocess.Popen` call. I'm not sure how to specify that all output needs to go to the logfile because it seems that `stdout` and `stderr` are the only parameters to control the flow of output and should be catching it.

I've attempted using `subprocess.PIPE` and then `proc.communicate` but it still goes to the screen. I've also attempted `shell=True` but that still goes to the screen as well. I also set `sys.stdout=logfile` and `sys.stderr=logfile` but still, it goes to terminal.

Comment: Do you happen to know what logging framework the Java code uses?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I don't know the logging framework the Java code uses. Also, I'm not familiar with Java at all to know what to look for... it's sort of a spider's nest of underlying java scripts that end up being used under the hood I think.

Comment: do you run it in bash console or in console in some IDE ? Did you try directly in bash `/path/scrpt argument 1> stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt` ? or with `... > output.txt 2>&1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, probably as expected, this was user error. There is an if/else that determines whether the output goes to a logfile or terminal that wasn't being triggered correctly. So the example code I originally posted wasn't actually being touched. I should have added a bunch of print statements to see this fact earlier... It is working as expected now.